# How to lower the last dimension of a Tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have an immature question.

For example, I got a tensor with the size of: `torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 64])`.

I need to turn it into another tensor with the size of: `torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 16])`.

Are there any right ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There exist many functions to achieve dimensionality reduction and the following are some examples:

1. randomly select 16 out of the 64 features
2. take the mean of every four features (64/4=16)
3. use a dimensionality reduction technique like [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)
4. apply a [linear transformation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html)
5. apply a [convolution function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html)

To give a satisfying answer, more information about why and what you want to do is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by: [@ptrblck_de](https://discuss.pytorch.org/u/ptrblck/)

**slice the tensor**

```
y = x[..., :16]
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 16])
```

**index it with a stride of 4**

```
y = x[..., ::4]
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 16])
```

**use any pooling (max, avg, etc.) layer (the same would also work using adaptive pooling layers)**

```
pool = nn.MaxPool2d((1, 2), (1, 4))
y = pool(x)
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 16])

pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(80, 16))
y = pool(x)
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 1, 80, 16])
```

**or manually reduce the last dimension with any reduction op (sum, mean, max, etc.)**